# Modelling data and accessing it using the DAO pattern

Tags: java, relational-database, data-modeling, dao

I'm creating a very simple application in Java that will be storing questions in an embedded Derby database. I've decided to use the DAO pattern for accessing the data in the database. I cannot make use of an ORM for this project.

A question will have data that I would normally model using a many to one relationship in a relational database. An example of this data would be:

- A question will have one category. One category will have multiple questions.
- A question will have a score of 1000, 2000 or 3000. A score will have many questions.

With the above in mind, I would create three tables (brackets indicate columns):

- Question (id, question, scoreId, categoryId)
- Score (id, score)
- Category (id, category)

**My first question is:**

Would modelling my data across three tables like I suggest above be bad practice/the wrong way to go about this? Is there any benefit in storing score and category in separate tables? Or would it be better to combine them into the Question table? A many to one relationship that links to a table with a single column (with the exception of id) seems redundant to me, as instead of storing an id referencing the Score/Category table, we can simply store the value of the category/score (since the category/score table does not store any additional information).

**My second question is:**

If modelling my data across separate tables is the correct approach, then how would I access the data using the DAO pattern? My confusion comes from the following:

I would create a DAO to populate a `Question` model object that would look a little something like this:

```
public class Question {
    String question;
    String category;
    Integer score;
}
```

I would create a concrete implementation of the DAO interface like this:

```
public class QuestionAccessObject implements QuestionDao {
    private static final String TABLE_1 = "QUESTION"; 
    private static final String TABLE_2 = "SCORE";
    private static final String TABLE_3 = "CATEGORY";

    @Override
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

        //Run a query with joins across the three tables and iterate over the result to populate the list
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't each DAO object only be concerned with a single table in the database? My approach listed above doesn't seem like the most correct way to go about this. Seperate tables would also make inserting data into the database very messy (I don't understand how I could take clean approach using the DAO pattern and multiple tables). Creating a DAO for the Score and Category tables just wouldn't really make sense.. (and if I did this, how would I populate my model?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would modelling my data across three tables like I suggest above be bad practice/the wrong way to go about this? Is there any benefit in storing score and category in separate tables....?

It's a matter of discussion. In case of `score` I rather stick this information with the `question`. On the other hand, the `category` would be in the separated table since more of the question would share the same category, so it makes a perfect sense.

> Shouldn't each DAO object only be concerned with a single table in the database?

Yes, DAO, an object should be concerned with a single source of data - as you say. I would certainly try to avoid any `ComplexDao` since those classes tend to get more complex and the number of methods increases over the time.

There exist a service layer to combine those results together and provide an output to the controller using the very same service.

Answer (score 2):

Modeling the data across separate tables is A correct approach (not necessarily the best).

Separating tables helps database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

One could argue that the DAO pattern implies that each DAO object is concerned with a single entity . Similar to how ORMs work, an entity could easily reference other entities.

When you query for a question you could also just return the category and score ids inside the question object and force the library user to fetch the score value and category value (lazy fetch) using those id values with their respective DAOs (score and category).

So I believe that what you're doing seems fine

Hope this helps